# Unit Test Cases failing but should pass

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, error-handling

I have built a customer shop where users enter the item that they want and based on the balance of their wallet, they are able to purchase or not.

Please see code
here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sleepy-wu-78gs5g?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A5%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A5%7D%5D&file=%2Ftest_shop.py

The code is split into two files, the one I am struggling with is test_shop.py

I created 5 unit tests to test this shop, but they all show 'FAILED' when it should be 'PASS'. I am new to testing so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any advice would be great.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from shop import InsufficientFundsError, items, money, welcome_to_shop, choose_item, choice

class TestShop(TestCase):
    def test_welcome_message(self):
        # Test if the display message appears
        result = welcome_to_shop(items)
        expected = "Welcome to our shop!\nHere are the items and their prices:\nitem1: £50\nitem2: £75\nitem3:£125"
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_successful_purchase(self):
        # Test a successful purchase
        result = choose_item(items, 'item2', money)
        expected_output = "Here's your item2!\nYou now have £25 left.\nThank you for visiting our shop!"
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Advice: create a [mre] and include it in the question.

Comment: The reason why the tests fail is because the `welcome_to_shop` and `choose_item` functions are returning the wrong result (or because you are expecting the wrong result in the tests).